# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\cos(\sqrt{n^2+a^2})}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}^\alpha}$ for $a$ and $\alpha$ reals.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I would like to show the following:

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{+ \infty} \frac{(- 1)^n}{r_n} \left[ \frac{\cos
   (r_n)}{r_n} \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{r_n^2} \right) + \sin (r_n) \left( 1 -
   \frac{1}{r_n^2} + \frac{x^2}{r_n^2} \left( - 1 + \frac{3}{r_n^2}
   \right) \right) \right] = -\frac{1}{3}$$
where $r_n = \sqrt{n^2+x^2+y^2}$, I know this is true because I computed this sum numerically for a lot of different $x$ and $y$. Surprisingly the result does not depend of $x$ and $y$ so I think there should be a way to make them disappear of the sum but I can't see how.

Here are the first term of the sum computed with a computer:

```
sum       || term
0.000000  || -0.236950
-0.236950 || -0.218228
-0.455178 || 0.018604
-0.436574 || 0.119464
-0.317110 || 0.062249
-0.254861 || -0.038544
-0.293405 || -0.071094
-0.364499 || -0.021665
-0.386164 || 0.039555
-0.346609 || 0.046553
-0.300056 || 0.002468
-0.297588 || -0.036931
-0.334519 || -0.030243
```

More generally my question is about how to compute an infinite serie such as:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\cos(\sqrt{n^2+a^2})}{\sqrt{n^2+a^2}^\alpha}$$ are there any tables that give simplification for this kind of serie ?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify: have I interpreted the problem correctly, that you intend that the denominator of the expression in your problem's title is $$\left[\sqrt{n^2 + a^2}\right]^\alpha ~?$$  Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Yes! $\alpha$ can be one to start but I'd like to find a formula for any $\alpha$

Comment: Your question is beyond my abilities.  My comment was designed only to confirm that you did **not** intend that the expression be interpreted as $$\sqrt{n^2 + \left[a^{(2^\alpha)}\right]}.$$